# ARP reply is not recognized from linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, system, call, arp, reply

I am facing the following situation:

A network application is calling `arp_send` kernel system call in order to send an ARP request for resolving an IP address. An ARP reply is received and send to kernel via netif_rx but linux kernel does not place any arp entry inside its arp cache. 
When `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enps025/arp_accept` has been set, then kernel has considered ARP reply and updated its ARP cache. 
My question is how can we reach to the same result by calling one or more system calls from user application? It seems that kernel does not trust unsolicited ARP replies. Is the only way to use `icmp_send` and let the kernel do the rest of the job?

Comment: What do you mean by "`arp_send` syscall"? There is no such syscall in Linux. How do you use it from user-space?

Comment: Of course there is an arp_send syscall. Please have a look here: https://books.google.gr/books?id=ALapr7CvAKkC&pg=PT745&dq=arp_send&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNrYvL6pzmAhUB7aYKHckkAyIQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=arp_send&f=false. Actually to be more precise it is a kernel module not a user space application.